# How to get winning odds from elo ratings in a league

Tags: probability

Consider that I have a basketball game (so there are no draws) and I have 2 teams with elo ratings already set ( not interested in points margin for this). If the elo ratings for the teams are e1 and e2 then I can calculate the winning chances of  team 1 via this algorithm:
Apologies for the code format below, e is equal to 10 to the power of (e2-e1)/400.

```
e = Math.pow(10, (e2 - e1) / 400);
odds = 1 / ( 1 + e);
```

All works as expected with the odds being a value between 0 and 1 and I can easily get the odds of the team 2 as 1-odds (not interested here in any influence of a home advantange either).

I now have a whole league with K (let's say 10) teams, each has its own elo rating(all ratings averaging out to 1200). The league is a simple round robin format with each team playing each other once at home and once away.
How can I calculate the odds of each team winning the league?